# Scale widget with splitted cursor

Tags: gtkmm

I'm developing a new gtkmm-based photo editor ([photoflow](https://github.com/aferrero2707/PhotoFlow)), and for one of my tools I need to define a smooth transition of output pixel values from "0" to "1" when the input values go from "min" to "max". 
In other words, the output values stay at "0" when "input < min", they go to "1" when "input > max" and vary linearly from "0" to "1" when "min < input < max".

Programming the transition itself is trivial. However, the photo editor is interactive and I have to provide a suitable GUI widget to set the "min" and "max" values. The easy solution would be to introduce two Gtk::Scale widgets, one controlling the "min" value and the other one the "max" value, but this would definitely not be very elegant and "professional", and would make the gui quite messy.

A more elegant and compact solution would be to have a sort-of Gtk::Scale widget with two cursors (or one cursor splitted in two halves), but I could not find any existing example of such a thing.

Should I implement the widget from scratch, deriving it from Gtk::Widget? Or is there a simpler solution? Or maybe some other open source project has faced the same problem and implemented the proper solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.